# Deploy to specific version

Tags: java, maven, google-app-engine

I'm using GAE, I usually do Deploy with a plugin for eclipse where it gives me the option to send it a version to upload, however I want to do it by command line, the command is as follows

```
mvn appengine:deploy
```

However I want to set the "version" parameter, but I do not know how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve it I added the following plugin in the pom:

```
 <plugin>
        <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
        <artifactId>gcloud-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.9.120.v20160803</version>
        <configuration>
            <gcloud_directory>/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk</gcloud_directory>
        </configuration>
</plugin>
```

And I executed the following command:

```
mvn gcloud:deploy -Dgcloud.version=VERSION
```